# Best way to test JPA Spring 3.1

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have written several JPA Repositories, Services and support classes for my Spring 3.1.1/JPA/Hibernate 4 web app.  However, I really want to write some unit and integration tests for it (I know, you are supposed to write those first).  I am using JavaConfig rather than XML, so I am wondering the best way to test.  Here is the particular problem I am trying to solve:

I have a @Configuration that declares DataSource, JpaTransactionManager, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, and all my respositories.  Obviously I don't want to start all that up for an integration test, so I thought I could use the EmbeddedDatabase and H2 to create an in memory database, populate with values, and then use my Repositories against it.  However, the documentation I have seen hasn't helped me put this together.   I have this:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
public class TestMenuService {

    private EmbeddedDatabase database;

    @Autowired
    private MenuRepository menuRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        database = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).setName("myschema")
                .addScript("classpath:schema.sql").build();

        menuRepository = new MenuRepository();
        Assert.assertNotNull(database);
    }
```

But the menuRepository does not get instantiated, so I tried creating a test version of my @Configuration

```
@Configuration } )
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "com.mycompany.service"} )
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource( "classpath:applicationContext.xml" )
@PropertySource( "classpath:test-application.properties" )
public class TestEdmConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MenuRepository menuRepository() {
        return new MenuRepository();
    }
```

My test-applicationContext.xml

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.servce.repository"/>
```

My test-application.properties:

```
db.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.username=sa
db.password=
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myschema

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

But this requires that I create all the datasources, etc mentioned above.  It seems like I am just duplicating all the support beans for this one.

Is there a way to have the reposository and embeddeddatabase isolated to my test without all the other dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test your repository in a full integration test I would image that you need everything else to be setup i.e. EntityManagerFactory, PlatformTransactionManager etc.

Since you are using Spring 3.1 I would suggest that you achieve this using bean profiles.

I would create two profiles one for tests and one for the application, each of which supplies a datasource.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class EmbeddedDataSource {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    // Return a H2 datasource
  }

}

@Configuration
@Profile("application")
public class ApplicationDataSource {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    // Return a normal datasource
  }

}
```

The you can create a test which starts up the spring context as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { MyConfigClass.class })
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class TestRepository {



}
```

In here you can specify the profiles where are active for the test.

Comment: I will try this approach, but I was hoping I could just use the embeddeddatabase, jpa and service without instantiating the whole stack for my integration tests.  What is the best approach for unit testing these components?

Comment: Well unit testing is very different to integration testing as I'm sure you're aware. Integration testing implies that you test against the whole stack. To unit test a bean you should use Mockito or similar to pass mock dependencies to the consturctor when you instantiate it manually. You can then test the behaviour in isolation.